# How to push values from an array to another array before using `splice` method in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `AngularJS` method to `splice` elements from middle of an `array` but I want to add the elements to be deleted to another array before using `splice` method.
Here is my code

```
$scope.method = function (index) {
            $scope.array2.push($scope.array1[index]);
            $scope.array1.splice(index, 1);
        }
```

when I am calling the method `array1[index]` values could be retreived but they not getting pushed into `array2`

here is my html code

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in array1">
    <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-ng-click="method($index)">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you're splicing inside a loop, altering the array as you go.

Comment: Is the array2 initialised?

Comment: js array `splice` returns array or removed elements. If `array1` is an `[]` the just `array1.splice(...).forEach(e=>array2.push(e));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the function [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
It will return your deleted value;

```
$scope.method = function (index) {
     if(! $scope.array2 ) $scope.array2 = [];
     $scope.array2 = $scope.array2.concat($scope.array1.splice(index, 1););
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I change only this part of your code.

```
$scope.method = function (index) {
        $scope.array2.push($scope.array1.slice(index, 1));
        $scope.array1.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Check this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/quethzel/9v9361c3/)